# My code not showing output because of segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char s[20];
    char upper;
        printf("\nEnter a word\n");
        scanf("%s",s);
    if(s[0]>='a'&& s[0]<='z')
    {
        upper = ('A' + s[0] - 'a');
    }
    else
    {
        upper=s[0];
    }
        printf("%s",upper);

    return 0;
}
```

This program makes the first letter of a word of uppercase. It's showing segmentation fault

Comment: `printf("%s", upper);` is using the wrong data type - have a look at compiler warnings. It should be `printf("%c", upper);`

Comment: Use `islower(s[0])` rather than checking character ranges yourself.

Comment: And use `toupper(s[0])` to convert it to uppercase.

Comment: Do you want to print the whole word or just the first character?

Comment: whole word with first letter capital not using any predefined function?